# URL routing and GAE

Tags: python, model-view-controller, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm a bit new to the MVC style of programming, and am working on 
a **Python/GAE/jinja2/webapp2** starter app to get my feet wet.

Is there any reason for me to be working at the Werkzeug level initially?
Or is that something to get into if webapp2 doesn't let me do something that I need to do?

I'm trying to understand the routing aspect, and it seems like that can 
be handled in various ways possibly. Is webapp2 a good place to start intitially with that,
and then if it needs to get more complex, what would be the next level if needed for more
complex URL routing?

I saw this on the webapp2 site docs:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/', HomeHandler),
    (r'/products', ProductListHandler),
    (r'/products/(\d+)', ProductHandler),
])
```

Is it not sequential in how it looks through them, in which case it would
be the more detailed line first in the list?

But the ***app.yaml*** file is sequential, right?
But only within the groupings - handlers, libraries, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

You can really work at whatever level you are comfortable (mostly dictated by your requirements).  How routing is implemented is very dependent on what lib/tools you use.

Pyramid and bobo are altenatives to the few you have listed, and implement routing completely differently.

app.yaml is processed in order, and as far as routing is concerned handlers are all that matter.

My personal preference for routing is anything that doesn't use regex's ;-)
(See pyramid and bobo)

I tend to have as few handlers listed as I can in app.yaml, and move the rest of the routing behaviour into the sprecific handler.

Rgds

Tim